# Need help getting report to correctly loop in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database with five tables (LDAP_Users, USERS, Courts Users, Accounts  and Supervisors) all linked by the Username in the LDAP table. I created a query retrieving the 10 fields from the five tables. I have also created a form to display these ten fields. The structure of the form is Supervisor is the group, under which is the supervisor’s name, email and phone number and then the  user who is supervised, the accounts the user can access and the type of account access.

I have the following code which my end state is to have the database iterate through each supervisor and retrieve the users they supervise as part of the report. Save the file to my network drive and ultimately take the email variable and send the particular report via email to the supervisor.

The problem, the first reports saves to the network, but the second consisting of 31 pages just continues to cycle, and does not move to the next supervisor. As far as the email piece, one I get the iterating worked out, I move on to the email.

I’m fairly new to VBA and would really appreciate gentle assistance.

```
Private Sub CreateReports_Click()
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String
    Dim StrSQL
    Dim stWhereStr As String 'Where Condition'
    Dim stSection As String 'Selection from drop down list
    Dim stfile As String

    StrSQL = "SELECT distinct [Sup] " & _
             "FROM ([OPDA ISSR - FedInvest Users by Account/Sup])"

    y = Year(date)
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("OPDA ISSR - FedInvest Users by Account/Sup")

    If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
        MsgBox "No data available for the Ledger Process routine."
    Else
        rst.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rst.EOF
            x = rst![Sup]
            stDocName = "FedInvest - ISSR Recertification Report"
            stWhereStr = "[OPDA ISSR - FedInvest Users by Account/Sup].[SUP]= '" & x & "'"
            stfile = "MYNETWORKDRIVE" & x & " - " & y & " FedInvest InvestOne Recertification.pdf"

            DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , stWhereStr
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, stfile
            DoCmd.Close acReport, stDocName
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I've been letting the code run, after 5 minutes, I have 10 reports completed. Not really sure what's going on with this, but it appears like the code is continuing to recreat files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you create an SQL string that filters by supervisor, you are opening the record for the entire table. Use a querydef to filter supervisors as follows:

Replace

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("OPDA ISSR - FedInvest Users by Account/Sup")
```

With

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rst = DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim qdTemp as DAO.QueryDef
Set qdTemp = db.CreateQueryDef("", StrSQL)
Set rs = qdTemp.OpenRecordSet()
```

Comment: Ron, I keep getting a compile error (I don't think I have the correct references) any suggestions?